# js, how to pass a click event?

Tags: javascript

```
<a id="button-a">a</a>
<a id="button-b">b</a>
```

I want click button a, the button b will also accept a click event;

click button b, the button a will also execute a click event.

how to make that in js? thanks.

Comment: Why not attach the same event handler to both?  You can't follow two links (as they go to different places), so I'm confused as to what *resulting* behavior you're after here.

Comment: @Nick Craver, no, they are not link to anywhere, they are two buttons to control jquery slider.

Comment: Why are they anchors? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button-a').click(function(e) {
    // do stuff
    if (this !== event.target) return; // avoid infinite loop
    $('#button-b').click(e);
});
```

Though as Nick Craver said, this is almost certainly the wrong solution; you should rather explain what the problem is.

Comment: this can do click `a` then make a click `b`. but if repeat the code, make click `b` first then do a click `b`, it failed. and this code not work in firefox.

Comment: @cj333 it is half of the code; you would need to do write same again with button-a and button-b swapped to add a click handler to b too.

Answer (score 0):

At any time, you can call `document.getElementById('button-b').click()` ~ like somewhere in the event that handles the a-click. (or the library appropriate call to get an elemeny by id, e.g `$('#button-b').click()`)

Comment: `$('.button-a').click(){
  $(this).click.('.button-b');
}` @Shad, Sorry for my poor js, this not work.

Comment: In your question, you used the element `id` to distinguish between the anchors. In the code you just commented, you are asking for elements with the **class** 'button-b'/'button-a'

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic, once you've seen how it works. Check out the JSFiddle example.

`<a id="button-a" onclick="document.getElementById('button-b').click();">[a]</a>
<a id="button-b" onclick="alert('something else');">[b]</a>`

http://jsfiddle.net/3eZPu/